# загрузка данных с 0 в начале

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть столбец данных, которые загружаются с excel.

| num |
| --- |
| 0312999 |
| 009999 |
| 005999 |

Но при загрузке данных в jupyter notebook 0 исчезают. Как экспортировтаь данные без изменений с 0.

Comment: решила этот вопрос, добавлением параметра dtype

Comment: Ну да, по умолчанию `pandas` считает такие данные числовыми, а у чисел передние нули не считаются. А если задать тип строка/объект, то данные будут прочитаны "как есть", без преобразования в числа.

Comment: Можете добавить свой ответ с куском кода, чтобы вопрос просто так не висел.

Answer (score 2):

```py
data = pd.read_excel('/Users/_____/Desktop/_____/_________/data.xlsx',
                     dtype={'Range Start': str, 'Range Stop': str, 'Delta': str})
```